# Remove Windows Developer Preview (No Password)

Tags: windows

I recently bought a Fujitsu tablet from a thrift store. It works, but it has the Windows Developer Preview (windows 8, I think) and two passwords that I don't know. What can I do to take either/both off?

Comment: You should simply reinstall Windows.  Windows 8 never had a “Developer Preview” that was released.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't seem to figure out how to do that without the password.

Comment: You should not need a Windows password to format a HDD and reinstall Windows.

Comment: How would I go about that? I've tried every method I can find but I need a password for most. Sorry this is a stupid question.

Comment: “You need a password for most” - This statement doesn’t make sense please clarify by editing your question

Answer (score 1):

Windows Developer Preview was, according to [this quick search result](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+developer+preview&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=f3067f6e96ee489993143bf37b1a318e&refig=6c2bb258f8e546b69c8d561eb83bbe44&cc=US&setlang=en-GB&elv=AQj93OAhDTi*HzTv1paQdni6dtXIwf6PQb1tPMVL13F7zJtayBeGAZsUT*brMvw9BOkFqwfdJw0unyYHVje29%21kyw09MVxH3m3bU6Qg*rqVO&plvar=0) a pre-W8 build for Developers to test W8.

Since you don't have password access, I would suggest taking a USB drive, at least 8GB in size, and make a Windows 10 Boot Disk.  Here is where you would get it:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

I don't know if a Windows 8.0 boot ISO exists anymore, but if you need Windows 8, I may suggest making a [Windows 8.1 boot ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO).  If you go this route make sure to gain control of these passwords somehow.  A long shot, but try [this answer](https://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/).

When you plug in the installation media, you have the option to format the disk and install from there, and if that is what you choose to do I would recommend going straight to Windows 10.

Comment: Any installation of Windows Developer Preview would have expired since it wasn’t technically a licensed product (Windows 10 Insider preview builds also expire).

Comment: Yes.  Would that prompt them on successful boot-up, or at successful login?  I would presume it would only have had an effect if the accounts in question were linked with an actual Microsoft Account?  At least, assuming you would have had to have a valid MS account to download the preview in the first place.

Comment: Now that I think about it, if you were able to get on there and upgrade, the only way you could "get away with it" without a license is if that account in question had a digital license: if the terms of the preview included the ability to obtain one for free.

So, there's a higher chance that isn't the case and you would, at least eventually resort to buying a product/license key.

@Ramhound - I made a few edits.

Comment: The Developer Preview build cannot be used forever, the build has long cease functioning, due to a time bomb just like every Windows 10 Insider Preview build has.  It was only intended for temporary use until Windows 8 was released, it is impossible to use the developer preview today, due to expiration.  However, none of that, explains “what password” the author is being promoted for.